# Modified mode highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want to modify the highlighting of my JS files, so that every line starting with `LOG` gets shown in a different color.<sup>1</sup>

I wrote the following

```
(require 'font-core)

(font-lock-mode 1)

(defface mg-js-pseudo-face '((t (:background "White"))) "..." :group 'faces)

(defvar mg-js-pseudo-regex "^[ \t]*\\(LOG .*\\)")

(defun mg-js-pseudo-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   `(
     (,mg-js-pseudo-regex 1 'mg-js-pseudo-face t)) ;;; <----- here
))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'mg-js-pseudo-hook)
```

It works well when highlighting the whole line (using `0` instead of `1` in the marked line). It does nothing at all, when used as is. Why?

<sup>1</sup>It's invalid JS, I know. It gets preprocessed by the server to `console.log` with some added information.

Comment: I tried this in js2-mode and it seemed to work with 1 (it highlighted the whole line, because the regexp matches the rest of the line). Put the cursor over the text you think should be highlighted, then use `C-u C-x =` (what-cursor-position) to find out what faces are there. That often helps me find which other font-lock rule is setting the face. When I tried it with your regexp, it was telling me `ms-js-pseudo-face`, `js2-external-variable`, and `js2-warning` were all fighting to be there. (Do you have a :background for one of those other faces?)